# maven-assembly-plugin attents to resolve dependencies using non configure repositories

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin

I am using the maven-assembly-plugin besides central maven repository only one private maven repository is defined in the maven projects. However, when I run mvn package I can see that the maven-assembly-plugin is looking in other maven repositories:

- Downloading from sonatype-nexus-snapshots
- Downloading from codehaus-snapshots
- Downloading from apache.snapshots
- Downloading from jvnet-nexus-snapshots
- Downloading from ossrh-snapshots
- Downloading from jcenter

And as it can not find ( and it should not find) the dependencies there it shows the following warning messages:

- [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata xxxx:comm-build:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/): nexus.codehaus.org
- [WARNING] Failure to transfer xxxx:parent:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of codehaus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.lsespace.orion:parent:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/): nexus.codehaus.org

Why is maven-assemble-plugin looking also in those repositories?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing a similar issue on my maven builds

Comment: Getting the same. I've configured a private repository but assembly does not want to look at it. Using assembly 3.3.0
Earlier versions (2.6) seems working.